# How to use the listnames stored on a list for performing list operations?

Tags: python, string, list

I a set of lists  and on those lists, I want to  perform is to find the first occurence on an element on each list. Suppose I have the following lists:

```
D1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
D2 = [2,7,6,5,4]
D3 = [1,2,6,8,7]
```

Now for each list, I want to find  out in  what position the element 2 first occurs. In this respect, I have first stored the names of the lists in a separate list. I have done it using this  code:

```
s_list = []

for i  in  range(1,4):

      s_list.append('D'+str(i))

print(s_list)
```

Now, using these names, I want to  perform the final operation using this code:

```
elem  = 2

index_pos = []

for i in s_list:

    k  = i.index(elem)
    index_pos.append(k)

print(index_pos)
```

However, on doing this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I have tried str(i) instead of i but the error remains the same.

It would really be helpful if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Because elements in ```lists``` are strings and not lists

Answer (score 1):

You can pack lists into a bigger list, so

```py
lists = [D1, D2, D3]
```

and then iterate over that, so

```py
elem  = 2
index_pos = []

for l in lists:
    k  = l.index(elem)
    index_pos.append(k)

print(index_pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you consider the list "D" into the `s_list` is not right and it is of type `strings`. Instead it could be done the following way.

Example:

```
D1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
D2 = [2,7,6,5,4]
D3 = [1,2,6,8,7]

s_list = [D1,D2,D3]
print(s_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 7, 6, 5, 4], [1, 2, 6, 8, 7]]
```

Here the code is right and the same:

```
elem  = 2
index_pos = []

for i in s_list:
    k  = i.index(elem)
    index_pos.append(k)

print(index_pos)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the elements of the list are **strings**. It is printed like:

```
['D1','D2','D3']
```

That is why you get an error. I suggest you define a function that takes some parameters and the return the indexes:

```
def retrun_indexes(ele,*args):
    return [i.index(ele) for i in args if ele in i]

D1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
D2 = [2,7,6,5,4]
D3 = [1,2,6,8,7]

print(retrun_indexes(2,D1,D2,D3))

# Output: [1, 0, 1]
```

You can pass any number of list an it will return the result. Just make sure that **always, the element to find is the first parameter to be passed in the function.**

Answer (score 1):

In this line `for i in s_list:` you are iterating over the `s_list` which just contains the names of the list as strings. Whereas really you want to iterate over the lists named `D1, D2, D3` however these are variables.

So I think this fixes that problem by iterating over the lists themselves and their names at the same time.

```
D1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
D2 = [2,7,6,5,4]
D3 = [1,2,6,8,7]

s_list = []
for i  in  range(1,4):
      s_list.append('D'+str(i))

index_pos = []
for d_list, list_name in zip([D1, D2, D3], s_list):
    index_pos.append((d_list.index(2), list_name))
print(index_pos)
```

Out:
`[(1, 'D1'), (0, 'D2'), (1, 'D3')]`